Film involving Roswell crash involving aliens and human mercenaries who plan on using the base's atomic bomb to wipe out humanity but love happens
The TV Tropes page for Roswell That Ends Well mentions an unnamed film with a decently detailed summary:

A TV movie involves a ship crashing near Roswell in 1947 with two Human Aliens and a number of genetically-engineered pilots (i.e. The Greys) aboard. The aliens are actually mercenaries, hired to "cleanse" Earth from humans for re-settlement by their employers. Roswell is specifically chosen, because the military base there has an atomic bomb, which one of the aliens (posing as a nuclear physicist) modifies with alien technology to boost its yield to allow it to wipe out everyone on the planet. However, he ends up falling in love with a beautiful widow and becoming fond of her son. He kills his partner/ex-lover, stops the countdown, and departs in a one-man ship to ensure that no other mercenaries are sent to finish the job. The military promptly covers up the event. Before departing, though, the alien reveals that Earth's humans are descended from a group of alien prisoners, whose transport crash-landed on the planet millennia ago.

Can anyone identify the work?

It looks like this is the 1999 Roswell: The Aliens Attack.

Two aliens escape from 1947 Roswell, New Mexico and set out to sabotage the Earth. The lady alien finds she enjoys sex and likes to seduce soldiers. However, the male eventually falls in love with an Earthling and decides to stop the female from setting off a nuclear weapon the two had developed.

This review, among others, mentions the widow.

This was packaged pretty well and promised an interesting spin on an interesting story - the alleged discovery and subsequent cover-up of a crashed alien spacecraft in New Mexico 1947. Anyway what you get is rubbish of the highest order and as soon as the cheap "fluoro green eyes" special effect is used to identify the aliens then you know what you're in for. Two human shaped aliens walk out of the crash - one male the other female. Well the male falls in love with a widowed airforce base worker and the female goes on a sex spree, and there is much disagreement between male and female on whether to blow up the earth. Won't give away the ending but it is so loaded with sweetness you'll want to be sick. There's also a hand-held alien gadget which shoots people, uploads information, downloads information, fries peoples brains, and heals people (most with a voice that sounds like the "good morning" you hear in some elevators).

Found with a search for tv film roswell base "atomic bomb" "widow"
